# Show XML data over background in Android

Tags: java, android, xml

When I show my list of XML data in my android app it shows each item with its own background. But I want the background image to be static and the list to show over it. below is the code for the listplaceholder.xml and the two activities. One has the XML functions in it and the other to show the data.

You can also downloaw the [eclipse page here](http://www.patriotsar.com/com.patriotsar.zip)

listplaceholder.xml:

```
<ListView
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

      <TextView  
android:id="@+id/item_title"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
android:background="#00000000"
android:padding="2dp"
android:textSize="20dp" />
<TextView  
android:id="@+id/item_subtitle"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#00000000" 
android:padding="2dp"
android:textSize="13dp" />
<TextView  
android:id="@+id/id_title"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:background="#00000000"
android:padding="2dp"
android:textSize="13dp" />
```

Xmlfunctions:

```
package com.patriotsar;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;


public class XMLfunctions {

    public final static Document XMLfromString(String xml){

        Document doc = null;

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is); 

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            System.out.println("XML parse error: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            System.out.println("Wrong XML file structure: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("I/O exeption: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return doc;

    }

    /** Returns element value
      * @param elem element (it is XML tag)
      * @return Element value otherwise empty String
      */
     public final static String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
         Node kid;
         if( elem != null){
             if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
                 for( kid = elem.getFirstChild(); kid != null; kid = kid.getNextSibling() ){
                     if( kid.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                         return kid.getNodeValue();
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         return "";
     }

     public static String getXML(){  
            String line = null;

            try {

                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://p-xr.com/xml");

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                line = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                line = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></results>";
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                line = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></results>";
            } catch (IOException e) {
                line = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></results>";
            }

            return line;

    }

    public static int numResults(Document doc){     
        Node results = doc.getDocumentElement();
        int res = -1;

        try{
            res = Integer.valueOf(results.getAttributes().getNamedItem("count").getNodeValue());
        }catch(Exception e ){
            res = -1;
        }

        return res;
    }

    public static String getValue(Element item, String str) {       
        NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
        return XMLfunctions.getElementValue(n.item(0));
    }
}
```

ShowXMLPAR.java:

```
package com.patriotsar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import com.patriotsar.XMLfunctions;


import android.app.ListActivity;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class ShowXMLPAR extends ListActivity {

     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


        String xml = XMLfunctions.getXML();
        Document doc = XMLfunctions.XMLfromString(xml);

        int numResults = XMLfunctions.numResults(doc);

        if((numResults <= 0)){
            Toast.makeText(ShowXMLPAR.this, "Geen resultaten gevonden", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
            finish();
        }

        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("result");

        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {                           
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    

            Element e = (Element)nodes.item(i);
            map.put("id","test:" +  XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "id"));
            map.put("name", "MIKE RAWERS:" + XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "name"));
            map.put("Score", "Score: " + XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "score"));
            mylist.add(map);            
        }       
//       
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(ShowXMLPAR.this, mylist , R.layout.listplaceholder, 
                        new String[] { "id", "name", "Score" }, 
                        new int[] { R.id.id_title, R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle });

        setListAdapter(adapter);


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding android:background="#00000000" to the ListView tag. This should set the background to transparent and allow the LinearLayout background to show through. You may need to do the same thing with each TextView.

Barry

Comment: If you do this, I'll believe you'll also want to follow the instructions here http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/listview-backgrounds.html regarding the color cache

Comment: I added both the transparent color and the cache hint but still not working. its weird when I do not set a background image in my <LinearLayout> each set of xml data is the height of the whole screen (lots of vertical scrolling). but when I remove it each set of xml data is only like 30-40px tall. Also the background is static at the bottom and then repeats for each list view item. IF that makes sense. lol Thanks for the help so far.